# Regular expression like string == string

Tags: regex

What would be regular expression for for example 'aa' to match only 'aa'

Comment: Why would you need to use a regular expression for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^aa$
```

The ^ and $ are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start and end of the line. If you have a multiline string you might also want to try:

```
\Aaa\Z
```

Which you need depends on what regular expression engine you are using and on whether or not there can be newlines in your string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match any doubled character:

```
/(.)\1/
```

If you want to match any repeated character:

```
/(.)\1+/
```

If you want to match only repeated letters:

```
/(\w)\1/
```

...etc...

If you explain your problem better, we can better help...

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a regex for this?

`string s = "aa";`

`bool match = (s == "aa");`